# In JQuery Cycle how do you get the src of the current slide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle

Im trying to work out the way to find the source of the current slide using JQuery cycle. I will be taking the source and using it to match the background image of another div using the 'after' method, it will change with each slide. This is what I have so far, all I need is to correct the var slideURL:

```
$('.home-slider').cycle({ pager: '.slider-pager', pause: '1', after: onSlideAfter });

        function onSlideAfter() {

            var slideURL = currSlide.content.find('img').attr('src');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or something?

Comment: Actually the below answer works great, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the current source like this

```
$('.home-slider').cycle({ pager: '.slider-pager', pause: '1', after: onSlideAfter });
function onSlideAfter() {
    var slideURL =this.src;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dWstA/

Comment: Ah ok that is much more simple than I expected! Thanks for the help!